# UIPageViewController with array of programatically generated views

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

So i need to create a UIPageViewController that shows a few views (1-25). 
 Basically i have a quiz app, and for every wrong question i save the question number (1-25) in a NSMutableArray. After the quiz is done i want to show the user which quiz answer was wrong. I have the methods that sets the view of the wrong answers (same methods i use to set the views in the quiz).
This keeps giving me 'Thread1:' errors.

```
PVCPagesViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PVCContentViewController.h"

@interface PVCPagesViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;


@end
```

.

```
PVCPagesViewController.m
#import "PVCPagesViewController.h"

@interface PVCPagesViewController () {
    NSArray *pages;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *pages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;


@end

@implementation PVCPagesViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //I think my problem is around here?

    PVCContentViewController *page1 = [[PVCContentViewController alloc] init];
    [page1 example1];
    PVCContentViewController *page2 = [[PVCContentViewController alloc] init];
    [page1 example2];
    PVCContentViewController *page3 = [[PVCContentViewController alloc] init];
    [page1 example3];
    PVCContentViewController *page4 = [[PVCContentViewController alloc] init];
    [page1 example2];


    // load the view controllers in our pages array
    self.pages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:page1, page2, page3, page4, nil];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    [self.pageController setDelegate:self];
    [self.pageController setDataSource:self];

    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.pages objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:0];
    [self.pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];

    [self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:[self.pageController view]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.pages indexOfObject:viewController];    // get the index of the current view controller on display
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:self.pageControl.currentPage+1];                   // move the pageControl indicator to the next page

    // check if we are at the end and decide if we need to present the next viewcontroller
    if ( currentIndex < [self.pages count]-1) {
        return [self.pages objectAtIndex:currentIndex+1];                   // return the next view controller
    } else {
        return nil;                                                         // do nothing
    }
}


- (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.pages indexOfObject:viewController];    // get the index of the current view controller on display
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:self.pageControl.currentPage-1];                   // move the pageControl indicator to the next page

    // check if we are at the beginning and decide if we need to present the previous viewcontroller
    if ( currentIndex > 0) {
        return [self.pages objectAtIndex:currentIndex-1];                   // return the previous viewcontroller
    } else {
        return nil;                                                         // do nothing
    }
}

- (void)changePage:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *visibleViewController = self.pageController.viewControllers[0];
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.pages indexOfObject:visibleViewController];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.pages objectAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage]];

    if (self.pageControl.currentPage > currentIndex) {
        [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];

    }
}

@end
```

.

```
PVCContentViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PVCPagesViewController.h"

@interface PVCContentViewController : UIPageViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label3;

-(void)example1;
-(void)example2;
-(void)example3;

@end
```

And lastly:

```
PVCContentViewController.m
#import "PVCContentViewController.h"

@interface PVCContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation PVCContentViewController
@synthesize label3,label2,label1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

-(void)example1{
    label1.text = @"View 1";
    label2.text = @"View 1";
    label3.text = @"view 1";
}

-(void)example2{
    label1.text = @"View 2";
    label2.text = @"View 2";
    label3.text = @"view 2";
}
-(void)example3{
    label1.text = @"View 3";
    label2.text = @"View 3";
    label3.text = @"view 3";
}

@end
```

I have borrowed the start source code from here:
https://github.com/hackin247/UIPageViewController

My source code:
https://github.com/4FunAndProfit/UIPageViewControllerHelp

Please let me know if you need anymore info!

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on [exception throw](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)?

Comment: I still get the same Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Comment: I know, but it should tell you where in your code you are getting your error. Also, check your `example:` methods in `PVCContentViewController.m` and use the accessor to get your label properties (`self.label1 ...`)

Comment: Yes, it tells me that the code breaks here: 
`[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];`
`self.label` made it open up the application with no warnings, but right now i doesn't work load up the PVCContentViewController on top of the PVCPagesViewController, i can maybe work with this!

Comment: Scratch that. It ''worked'' but only because it never really loaded the viewcontroller objects. It tried:
`PVCContentViewController *page1 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"content"];`
But then i get the same error again..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `pageController` with the `self.pages` array directly?

`[self.pageController setViewControllers:pages direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];`

I don't see the point of creating yet another array(`viewControllers`). Maybe this is causing issues when trying to get the next page since the `pageController` only has a single `viewController` (`[self.pages objectAtIndex:0]`) but the "data source" says it should have more based on the `self.pages.count`.

Comment: Hey man, i got it to work, thank you so much time though, it helped alot!

Comment: This is how i did it: https://github.com/4FunAndProfit/UIPageViewControllerWithMethods
Thanks alot for the help